How do ferry flight operators like Nomadic Aviation maintain type rating for their pilots?
The recent VT-EVA ferry flight from BOM-Paine Field - US desert really piqued my interest about how the crew are arranged for such flights?
B747-400 is a pretty rare aircraft now a days, and I don't think most scheduled airlines allow their pilots to freelance. Nomadic Aviation on their website mention they have a dedicated crew of 30 pilots
Yet, how do these pilots maintain their type ratings given they often fly unique aircraft only once in a 3 or 6 month period. How do they satisfy requirements of 70 flying hours to maintain type rating?
I did refer to Who flies planes on ferry flights but the answers there don't exactly focus on qualifications of pilots for ferry flights.
Is it the case that ferry flights are exempt from exact type rating requirements for pilots somehow?

Ferry flights use different regulations in most jurisdictions. No need to be “current” on type.

I would assume they apply for a waiver.
